# An Electric Riley

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

Because I see Riley's riddle too often lately when I see this word, a puzzle just suddenly appears in my mind ._.

Then, let's try how fun it is:

> My prefix needs an electricity
>
> My infix is kind of electricity
>
> My suffix is good for moving an electricity
>
> My whole is just a confusing city

What is the word?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Taking a gamble on

> Macau

My prefix needs an electricity

> Mac - an Apple Mac

My infix is kind of electricity

> ac - alternating current

My suffix is good for moving an electricity

> Au - gold's high conductivity and resistance to corrosion make it useful in industry.

My whole is just a confusing city

> Macau - A Special Administrative Region of China west of Hong Kong.

Comment: sounds convincing to me.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, and you literally can "Taking a gamble on" there :)

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by the other answer, one could also argue for

> Vegas

My prefix needs an electricity

> $V$, the symbol for electric potential, which according to Ohm's law needs an electric current to form across a resistor

My infix is kind of electricity

> $E$, the symbol for an electric field, which is arguably the same as electricity

My suffix is good for moving an electricity

> GaS, Gallium Sulphide is a semiconductor

My whole is just a confusing city

> Important landmarks such as The Strip are outside Vegas' city limits. Also, what happens in Vegas...

Comment: wow, a very good guess! and you literally can still "Taking a gamble on" there :) but for the last part I think it's not really fit, as what's confusing is the landmark

Comment: @malioboro I worked from the other post with the "spoiler" tags hidden, making the "gamble" the inspiration for this. I agree, the last clue does not fit nearly as well as for the other answer.